# Working bash command breaks when in function or alias

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, alias

When I run this command interactively it outputs the expected log name (last modified, per Service name file).

```sh
# Gets last active service log in a /environmentsDir/serviceName/var/output/logs directory. You need to cd 1st.
ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'
```

When I try to escape it for an alias expression or a function, can't get it right, always fails for different reasons.

What would be the right way of escaping it, in CLI, to get a function or alias working?

For instance if I'd like to tail that log file the function or alias should allow me to:

```
lastLog=escaped(ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}')

tail -f $(lastLog)
```

### Edit:

Adding outputs of trying a function:

```
21:55:28-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'
serviceName.2022-04-12-21
21:55:33-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog() {
logbash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
21:55:42-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog() { \
logbash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
21:55:46-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog { \
> ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'
head: invalid option -- 't'
Try 'head --help' for more information.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
21:56:10-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog() { ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'; }
logbash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
21:56:41-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog() { ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'; }^C
21:56:56-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog() {ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}' ; }
logbash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
21:57:14-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog { ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}' ;  }
logbash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

# This one doesn't blow up but still fails when executed:
21:57:35-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ function lastLog { ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}' ;  }
21:57:47-user@host:/environmentsDir/env/serviceName/var/output/logs$ lastLog 
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

### 2nd Edit:

@john-kugelman 's answer was correct, and I had already tried it, unsuccessfully. The added problem was, as pointed out by @gordon-davisson 's comment below, I had added an alias with same name as function, which was gaining precedence and was also broken.

Comment: `Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]` well, it's not surprising that your command breaks sometimes, given that you don't use any quoting nor `--` in it

Comment: @Fravadona it did work on CLI, as shown on 1st output line. Tried many variants escaping and with literal `' escaping inner \' '  ` but no luck.

Comment: Is the shell `bash`?

Comment: If you already have an alias by that name, it'll interfere with attempts to define it as a function. Try `unalias lastLog`, and *then* define it as a function.

Comment: `echo $0 /usr/bin/logbash` @Fravadona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about functions is that they don't require any special escaping. Just put the command exactly as written inside a function and you're good to go:

```
lastLog() {
    ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'
}
```

You can type a multi-line function definition at an interactive shell just like that. But if you want it as a one-liner, it would be this, with a semi-colon appended to the command before the closing curly brace:

```
lastLog() { ls -tl | head -n20 | grep $(basename $(pwd | egrep '/environmentsDir/env/[^\/]+' -o)) | head -n1 | awk '{print $(NF)}'; }
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work, see edits.

Comment: As @gordon-davisson mentioned above in Question's comments, it was a buggy alias that was blocking the fn to be executed. Marking accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified, using the shell's parameter expansion:

```sh
lastLog() {
  local dirname=${PWD#/environmentDir/env/}     # remove the prefix
  dirname=${dirname%%/*}                        # remove the suffix

  ls -tl *"$dirname"* | head -n1
}
```